# Sbt exec a process and give the hand to this process

Tags: scala, process, sbt

I would like to have sbt start a command as with [!](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Process.html) but instead of waiting the end of the process, give the hand to the process.

Like execve, the new process keep input and output but the sbt process exist no more, replaced by the new process.

Hear I talk about sbt but it's could be the same for any scala applications.